# Binding contextual information into a GraphQL type?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Let's say that I have two GraphQL types:

```
type Student {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Classroom {
  id: ID!
  students: [Student!]!
}

type Query {
  classroom(id: ID!): Classroom!
}
```

So then I can run a query like so:

```
{
  classroom(id: 1) {
    id
    students {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And with the correct resolvers set in place, this would return me the students associated with a particular classroom.

However, let's say that I wanted to find some information relating to a student's performance in a classroom, let's say:

```
averageTestScore: Int!
numAbsences: Int!
```

I assume I would need a wrapper type, like:

```
type ClassroomStudent {
  averageTestScore: Int!
  numAbsences: Int!
  student: Student!
}
```

I was wondering if there was a standardized way to do this? Additionally, I have many existing queries that bind `Classroom` to `Student` directly, so introducing `ClassroomStudent` would be a breaking API change. Is there a way for me to architect my APIs to allow these sorts of changes to be quite organically introduced without introducing backwards-incompatible changes?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern in Relay-compliant schemas is to attach fields like that onto the relevant edge:

```
type StudentConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo
  edges: [StudentEdge!]!
}

type StudentEdge {
  cursor: String!
  node: Student!
  averageTestScore: Int!
  numAbsences: Int!
}

type Classroom {
  students: StudentConnection!
  # other fields
}
```

However, this is still effectively the same as introducing the `ClassroomStudent` you proposed. Either way, the trick to introducing a change like this without breaking your API is to keep (and deprecate) the previous field and introduce your new one under a different name:

```
type Classroom {
  students: [Student!]! @deprecated(reason: "Use classroomStudents instead")
  classroomStudents: [ClassroomStudent!]!
  # other fields
}
```

It may not look pretty, but it'll let your client apps transition without dealing with breaking changes.

Another potential option:

```
type Student {
  performance(classroom: ID!): StudentPerformance
}
```

You can add a field to student with a required classroom argument. This forces the client to potentially provide the same classroom ID twice if querying for a specific classroom with students, but it's a valid option. It also has the added benefit of allowing you to query students directly without necessarily fetching classroom data:

```
query {
  students {
    id
    performance(classroom: 1) {
      averageTestScore
      numAbsences
    }
  }
}
```